# What is a "suspended" task in Windows 2008?

Tags: windows, process

I happened to be looking at Resource Monitor on Windows 2008 and noticed bsdiff.exe (OfficeScan) in a "suspended" state. Could somebody please explain what this means and why a process might be in this state? I was going to grab a screenshot but it's gone now.

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to suspend tasks has been in Windows for a long time, the easiest way to do this in other versions is to use [Microsoft / Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

A suspended task is a normal process that is in a suspended state. When suspended, it consumes the same amount of memory, but no CPU cycles.

Suspended tasks have not really been used that much in Windows, but, it will be a big feature of Windows 8 where by all Metro processes that are not in use will automatically suspend.

As for usage in other editions of Windows, it is possible to suspend programs, it just isn't widely used. There is certainly nothing wrong or anything to worry about by doing it.

Comment: _"When suspended, it consumes the same amount of memory"_ - It's not true in this form, see [MSDN Blogs - Reclaiming memory from Metro style apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/04/17/reclaiming-memory-from-metro-style-apps.aspx). Anyway, I upvoted your answer, because it was informative. ;)

Comment: What else can cause a process to be suspended if you don't manually suspend it? I have a problem where Adobe Reader is taking about 2 minutes to start, and during that time it appears as "suspended".

Comment: It appears that many Windows 10 store apps (or at least the official ones) have the ability to enter suspended state automatically as soon as you alt-tab away or minimise them. Also when you close them, if you enable them as a background application, they don't fully close, instead they linger as suspended process. Apparently to help reloading them faster, but I am suffering from screen tears from this feature.

Comment: Is it somewhat equivalent to SIGSTOP on Unix?